# How to change value of Object inside an Array?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the values of the objects inside an array. I have created an object which I insert in every loop in an array.

If encountered with a missing value, I want to update the values of the existing object.

When the loop runs, it always enters the last object details from the api into the array.

Here; the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n49Qc.png

```
var msg = data.message; // messages array from api
let body;
let posts = [];// empty array created

//object structure
let post ={
    id:'',
    desc: '',
    creator: '',
    time: '',
    likes: 0,
    attachment: '',
};
for(let i in msg){
    if(msg[i].body.includes(':')){ //if message body include object notation ':'
      body = JSON.parse(msg[i].body); // parse text message body into json
      if(body.contentDescription){ //if content is true
        post.id = body.postId; //id
        post.creator = body.createdUserName; //post creator
        post.time = body.publishedDate; //post publish date
        post.desc = body.contentDescription; //post content

        posts.push(post);
      }
      else if(posts.length > 1){
        for(let j in posts){
          if(posts[j].id === body.postId){
            console.log(posts[j].id);
            if(body.likeCount){ //if likeCount is true
              posts[j].likes += 1; //increase like count
            }else if(body.attachmentId){ //of Attachment is true
              posts[j].attachment = body.attachmentId; // update    attachement value
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      }


    }


};
```

Please help where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Please enter your sample data, and expected output

Comment: Sample Data: https://i.imgur.com/jkXnrrG.png and Sample Result: https://i.imgur.com/wXx6T0t.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript are sent via a link to the piece of memory. So when you change your `post` you are changing all the posts because all of them are looking to the same piece of memory.

You can change your code in a next way so it start working correct

```
...
if(body.contentDescription){ //if content is true
    let postItem = Object.assign({}, post); // Coping an object so breaking the memory link
    postItem.id = body.postId; //id
    postItem.creator = body.createdUserName; //post creator
    postItem.time = body.publishedDate; //post publish date
    postItem.desc = body.contentDescription; //post content

    posts.push(postItem);
  }
...
```

However, there is more than one way to skin a cat so this is not the only solution.

Comment: Great!!! It's working to get me the ids correctly but I am not able to update the values if same ids are detected. Any suggestions??

Comment: It seems to me that `break` is not in the right place. It breaks the loop just after the first iteration. It should be one layer up to break after the duplicate was found.

Comment: I just used forEach() method in place of for-in and it worked!